# How to work around compiler built-in types in C standard header files

Tags: c, header-files

I am working on a static analysis tool for C. I need to pass the code being analysed through the C preprocessor so that the tool can see the library function prototypes, type definitions, etc. Unfortunately both with clang on Mac OS X and gcc on Linux distros, some of the standard header files refer to compiler built-in types like `__builtin_va_list` that my tool doesn't know about. Does anyone have any suggestions for how to work around this. One possibility, if it's available somewhere, would be a vanilla-flavoured set of header files that produce C that conforms strictly to the standard. The header files don't have to map to any ABI, as the tool doesn't need to compile and run the code: they just have to give the API promised by the C standard. Any suggestions will be gratefully received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of finding a set of *standard* standard header files, you can just use a set of empty files with the expected names and pass the source code through the compiler preprocessor with a `-Idirectory` option. Your syntax analysis tool should be able to deal with the remaining symbols.

It would be useful to have a preprocessor option in addition to `-dI` to preserve `#include` lines **instead** of handling them.

In the mean time, you can try using the include files from my [**nolibc**](https://github.com/qlibc/nolibc) repository.

Comment: Thanks, but empty files won't work. I need the type definitions, function prototypes etc., as the static analyser needs to do type synthesis as well as just syntax checking (and even for syntax checking you need to know what names are types).

Comment: You can use header files from a different, simpler library or even create your own from the text of the C standard, but some constructions will still be problematic: `va_list` cannot be an opaque type. I have a set that might fit your purpose, I shall publish it on github tonight.

Comment: That would be great.

Comment: Make your tool a clang module or a gcc plugin maybe, this way you have easy access to the compiler builtins.

Comment: @RobArthan: I updated the answer with a link to the repository. Tell me if it works

Comment: It seems to do exactly what I wanted. Many thanks for making available such a useful resource.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Thanks for the suggestion, but that would involve an awful lot of work. It's a possibility for the future though.